# A Java builder class with JsonDeserialize Optional fields set as Optinal.empty. Set default value when JsonDeserialize

Tags: java, java-8, json-deserialization, jsonparser

Set default values when deserializing JSON

```
ObjectMapper om;

String jsonStudent = {"id":"1"}
```

parse student json to Student object

```
Student student = om.readValue(message.getBody(), Student.class);
```

Student calss

```
@Getter
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Student.StudentBuilder.class)
@Builder(builderClassName = "StudentBuilder", toBuilder = true)
public class Student {
    private Optional<String> studentName;
    private String id;
    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class StudentBuilder {
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the *Student object* fields like

> id : 1
>
> studentName : Optional.empty.

But Deserialize Student name treat as null.
How can i handle this. without using Implicit default values  and All Arg contructors.

Comment: Don't declare data members variables as optional. it is bad practice.

Comment: @HadiJ In my new bissines case use that class. Optional is already existing field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson has a set of modules that deal with JDK 8 datatypes, including Optional.

First, add the latest version as a Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
   <version>2.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, all you need to do is register the module with your ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```

NOTE: As [@Hadi_J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3669698/hadi-j) already said, declaring json object properties as `Optional` is bad practice!